# Topological exercice

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have this topological space $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau)$ where the basis of $\tau$ is $\sigma=\{\Omega_r, r\in \mathbb{R}_+\}$ where $\Omega_r=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, x=r \cos(t),y=r \sin(t); t\in[0,2\pi[\}$

let $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, |x+y|>2\}$

We have that $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2, y>2-x\}\cup\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2, y<-2-x\}$

How to find $\overline{A}$ and $\overset{\circ}{A}$ ?

Edit 1: i find that $\overset{\circ}{A}=\emptyset$

Thank you

Comment: I think this basis generates the discrete topology, so the closure and the interior of $A$ coincide with $A$. To be more precise, this does not look like a basis (for any topology), but used as a subbasis it generates the discrete topology. Perhaps I overlooked something ... reading the definitions one more time.

Comment: how to see that $\tau=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ @Mirko please

Comment: It can't be the discrete topology, because no base contains $(0,0)$.  It also can't be a basis, because the intersection of two basis sets does not contain a basis set.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you are right, I was about to indicate that too

Comment: If this is a problem from a problem set, it is best to copy it exactly as is, and not paraphrase, because as currently written, there is no topology with those sets as a basis.

Comment: your question is inconsistently stated, please improve it, otherwise there could be no meaningful answer.

Comment: this a exercise in exam of topology i copy it exactly as given

Comment: Is it maybe $y=r\sin(t)$, and not $y=\sin t$? That would make the question answerable.

Comment: yes you are right sorry

Comment: Well, $\Omega_r$ is an ellipse (just the curve, not the inside) with vertices at $(0,\pm1)$ and could be thin or fat. Two such ellipses intersect only at the vertices and the intersection does not contain an ellipse of this form, so this is not a basis for any topology. The union of such ellipses does not cover the plane (except for most of the horizontal infinite strip between $y=\pm1$, so again this is not a basis.

Comment: In your definitions, is $0$ considered a member of $\mathbb R_{+}$? @Vrouvrou

Comment: @Mirko Actually, OP just updated to $y=r\sin t$, so the open sets are unions of circles. Unclear if $0\in \mathbb R^{+}$. If so, every open set is closed and visa versa.

Comment: aah, ok, so after the edit, $\Omega_r$ is the circle centered at the origin with radius $r$. I assume $\mathbb R^+=[0,\infty)$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}_+=[0,+\infty)$

Comment: The closure is all points swept by $A$ using rotation around the origin. Try to prove this, and then think about the interior.

Comment: $X\in \overline{A}\Longleftrightarrow \forall V\in \mathcal{V}_X, V\cap A\neq \emptyset$ where $X=(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ i know that $A\subset \overline{A}$ but i don't know how to prove that $A=\overline{A}$

Comment: each point $(x,y)$ has exactly one minimal (i.e. contained in all other) neighborhood, namely the circle centered at the origin passing trough $(x,y)$. Suppose said circle $C$ intersects $A$ at a point $(a,b)$. Then every neighborhood of $(x,y)$ contains $C$ and $(a,b)$, in particular intersects $A$. Hence $(x,y)$ belongs to the closure of $A$. My previous comment did not suggest that $A=\overline A$, I don't think this is true (my much older comment about the discrete topology must be ignored as it was the result of the confusion caused by imprecise statement of your problem).

Comment: @Mirko I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any point $p=(x,y)$ let $C(p)$ denote the circle centered at the origin passing through $p$. Note that $C(p)=\Omega_r$ where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. 
Every open set is the union of such circles (including possibly the degenerate circle $\Omega_0$ consisting of the origin only).

For every point $p$, the circle $C(p)$ is a neighborhood. Moreover, $C(p)$ is the smallest open set containing $p$, in the sense that $C(p)$ is the intersection of all neighborhoods of $p$, and is contained in each such neighborhood.

So now, take *any* set $A$ (in general, not necessarily the same set as in your question). Suppose $p$ is such that $C(p)$ does not intersect $A$. Then, since $C(p)$ is open, it follows that $p$ does not belong to 
$\overline A$. More generally, $C(p)$ and $\overline A$ do not intersect.

Now consider the case when $C(p)$ intersects $A$, say at a point $(a,b)$. 
Since $C(p)$ is the smallest neighborhood of $p$, it follows that every neighborhood $U$ of $p$ must intersect $A$ (at $(a,b)$), i.e. 
$(a,b)\in C(p)\cap A \subseteq U\cap A$. It follows that $p\in\overline A$. Moreover, every point $q\in C(p)$ also belongs to 
$\overline A$, since $C(q)=C(p)$ hence every neighborhood of $q$ must contain $C(p)$ which intersects $A$ at $(a,b)$. Thus, $C(p)\subseteq \overline A$, when $C(p)$ intersects $A$.

It follows that $\overline A$ is the union of all circles centered at the origin that intersect $A$. You may visualize this by rotating $A$ a full revolution around the origin and considering the set of all points swept by $A$ in this way: This set is $\overline A$.

For the interior, a point $p$ belongs to $\overset{\circ}{A}$ only if the circle $C(p)$ is entirely contained in $A$. The union of all such circles (if any) is the interior of $A$. (If no such circles exist then $A$ has empty interior.) (It is possible to describe $\overset{\circ}{A}$ in terms of rotation, bit this is not as elegant as in the case of $\overline A$. You may revolve the complement of $\mathbb R \setminus A$ around the origin, obtaining say a set $T$ of all points swept in this way, and then $\mathbb R \setminus T$ is the interior of $A$.)

For the specific set $A$ that you consider, 
$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, |x+y|>2\}=
\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2, y>2-x\}\cup\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2, y<-2-x\}$,
this is the set of all points distance more than $\sqrt2$ away from the anti-diagonal $y=-x$. The one circle of interest here (and centered at the origin) is $\Omega_{\sqrt{2}}=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=(\sqrt{2})^2=2\}$, touching the lines $x+y=2$ and $x+y=-2$ at the points $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ respectively. This circle does not intersect $A$, and no smaller circle centered at the origin intersects $A$, that is, $\Omega_r\cap A=\emptyset$ whenever $r\le\sqrt{2}$. All bigger circles centered at the origin do intersect $A$, that is, $\Omega_r\cap A\not=\emptyset$ whenever $r>\sqrt{2}$. Make a picture, convince yourself that following the above procedure you would obtain $\overline A=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2>2\}=\cup \{\Omega_r:r>\sqrt{2}\}$, and 
$\overset{\circ}{A}=\emptyset$.
(For $\overset{\circ}{A}$ note that for any $r\ge0$ the point $(\frac r{\sqrt2},\frac{-r}{\sqrt2})$ is on the intersection of $\Omega_r$ and the anti-diagonal, hence $(\frac r{\sqrt2},\frac{-r}{\sqrt2})\in\Omega_r\setminus A$. Thus $\Omega_r$ is not contained in $A$, for any $r$.)

> ! 
>   Old incorrect version (edited and corrected above: I had confused the defining condition $|x+y|>2$ of $A$ with $|x|+|y|>2$).
>   For the specific set $A$ that you consider, 
>   $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, |x+y|>2\}$, this is the complement of the (filled in, closed) square with vertices $(0,\pm2)$ and $(\pm2,0)$. The two circles of interest here (and centered at the origin) are $\Omega_{\sqrt{2}}=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=(\sqrt{2})^2=2\}$ (touching the square at the points $(\pm1,\pm1)$) and $\Omega_{2}=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=2^2=4\}$ (intersecting the square at its vertices). Make a picture, convince yourself that following the above procedure you would obtain $\overline A=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2>2\}=\cup \{\Omega_r:r>\sqrt{2}\}$ and 
>   $\overset{\circ}{A}=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2>4\}=\cup \{\Omega_r:r>2\}$.

Comment: In my mind $\overset{\circ}{A}=\emptyset$ because $X\in \overset{\circ}{A}\Longleftrightarrow \exists ~\text{open} ~\Omega_r, x\in \Omega_r\subset A$ and all the open sets are centred in (0,0) which is not in A

Comment: I apologize for misreading your definition of $A$, I made the necessary corrections in my answer. Please keep in mind that $\Omega_r$ is only (the circumference of) the circle (not the entire disk), so in particular $(0,0)$ never belongs to $\Omega_r$ (with only exception when $r=0$).

Comment: Hello @Vrouvrou, do you find any more inaccuracies after the edit? Please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21954/op-doesnt-mark-question-as-answered and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18746/acceptability-of-asking-a-user-with-a-low-accept-rate-to-accept-an-answer

Answer (score 1):

If $f:\mathbb R^{2}\to[0,\infty)$ is defined as $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, then show that $U$ is open in your topology if and only if $U=f^{-1}(X)$ for some $X\subseteq [0,+\infty)$.

This also defines the close subsets of $\tau$.

It's basically the discrete topology defined on $[0,+\infty)$ and pulled back through $f$. In particular, $\Omega_r=f^{-1}(r^2)$.

For any $A\subseteq \mathbb R^{2}$, $\overline{A}=f^{-1}(f(A))$ and $\overset{\circ}{A} = (\overline{A^c})^c$.

Now you just have to figure out what that is for the given $A$.

Comment: I don't understand your unswer

Comment: i do a pictur and i see that $\overline{\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A}=\mathbb{R}^2$ so $\overset{\circ}{A}=\emptyset$ right ?

Comment: Is there any circle around $0$ contained entirely in your set? No, so the interior is empty, correct.